# look for in a JavaScript script keywords

Tags: javascript, regex

They are a beginner with regex and I'm trying to write a script to highlight the keywords contained in the javascript file

```js
var text = " 'function'  XfunctionX function Xif(){}else{} ......";
var result = text.replace(/(function|if|else)/gi,function(x){
  return '<span style="color:red">' + x + '</span>';
});
$('body').html(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

how do I replace the required keywords excluding those not interesting?

Comment: why not also highlights the keywords like **XfunctionX**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to replace the word when it's in the middle of another word, change your regular expression to use `\b` to match word boundaries.

```js
var text = " 'function'  XfunctionX function Xif(){}else{} ......";
var result = text.replace(/\b(function|if|else)\b/gi,function(x){
  return '<span style="color:red">' + x + '</span>';
});
$('body').html(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```